# Cassandra data modelling partition key

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have two tables in cassandra for my project.

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS post_by_user
(topic_id varchar, 
post_id UUID,
title varchar, 
post_body varchar, 
user_id varchar,  
view_count int,
date_created date,
primary key (user_id, post_id))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_id DESC);



create table IF NOT EXISTS post_by_topic
(topic_id varchar, 
post_id UUID,
title varchar, 
post_body varchar, 
user_id varchar,  
view_count int,
date_created date,
primary key (topic_id, post_id))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_id DESC);
```

Now I want to create a table for top viewed post based on view_count.
What should be the partition key for the table since there could be multiple topics and users? is there any possibility for materialzed view?

There is also one way to keep the partition key some constant value.

Please suggest...

Answer (score 1):

Creating materialized view on one of your tables above cannot help you compute overall top-viewed posts. As an illustration, if we create a materialized view over the `post_by_user` as follows, we can only compute top-post for each user:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW toppostforuser AS
   SELECT post_id FROM post_by_user
   WHERE post_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND view_count IS NOT NULL AND date_created IS NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (user_id, post_id, view_count, date_created)
   WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (view_count desc);
```

You would need a table with the partition key equal to just the `post_id` over which a materialized view can be created to compute overall top-viewed posts.

**Note**: If you split your `date_created` into separate columns such as `year`, `month`, `day`, you could also compute daily top-posts, monthly top-posts etc.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW dailytoppostforuser AS
   SELECT post_id FROM post_by_user
   WHERE post_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND view_count IS NOT NULL AND year IS NOT NULL AND month IS NOT NULL AND day IS NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, year, month, day), post_id, view_count)
   WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (view_count desc);
```

Reference: [Materialized views in Cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views)

Comment: This will not work in cassandra....if you make post_id as partition key there is no point in sorting ..since post_ids are unique. You cannot get records based on view_count without post_id and user_id

Comment: I seem to have mixed-up post-id & user-id in my initial answer. Have edited it. In the current materialized view, you will need just the user-id to fetch  the top post for that user.